# Proof of address for bank account for UK spouse of Tier 2 work visa

Tags: united-kingdom, bank-account, non-resident, documents

My colleague has a Tier 2 visa to work at our company here in the UK (probably for the next 5 years). He and his family are from Indonesia. Bills are all in his name, but his wife is not being allowed to open a bank account as she is unable to show a utility bill in her name. Memberships such as library card are not accepted.

Generally speaking, how can a spouse prove their address if no utility bills are in their name? Which avenues are open to the spouse of a foreign worker?

Comment: do they have a rental or lease agreement for the place they living?

Comment: @mhoran_psprep rental agreement is also in my colleague's name as the landlord would not accept spouse as named on the lease for the same reasons.

Comment: I corrected the tag from united-states to united-kingdom to match the text. Please re-edit if this is not correct for any reason.

Answer (score 1):

Just add her name to the utilities accounts. He will need to do this as the existing account holder, but there should not be any problem in just ringing them up and asking to add her to the account.

Answer (score 0):

[This question](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/85/how-to-open-up-your-first-uk-bank-account-without-proof-of-address) on expatriates.se seems to have a fairly good summary of various approaches (and is from 2014, so hopefully current). Can't speak to personal experience, though...